# Start Windows application from batch file without leftover command window

Tags: windows, batch

I have a simple batch file that sets some necessary per-session path information and then launches an application:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\473_x64\lib;C:\Qt\jom
start C:\Qt\qt_creator_220_x64\bin\qtcreator.exe
```

It is working fine except that it keeps open a ghost command window. This command windows shuts down when the application shuts down. To be clear, the command window that comes up when I initially double-click the batch file closes. It is a new window that opens up. How do I prevent this second window from displaying? I would like to just double-click on a short cut to the batch file and it open the application as if I had double-clicked on the application itself. (Plus, of course, setting the necessary path information.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm curious what your application does. Because this has nothing to do with the batchfile. The batch file only opens one window and clearly closes.  Any subsequent windows are caused by QTcreator.

Look at this question and see if the edits are similar to yours.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760323/why-does-my-qt4-5-app-open-a-console-window-under-windows

Comment: Success! It was rather similar to that link. I built Qt Creator in debug mode, which added the testlib library, which made it use the console subsystem. Building it in release mode took out that library and now it opens without the extra window.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only the one command, you can get rid of `start` so that it opens in the same process.

Alternatively and a better solution is to use the `/b` switch so that start does not open a new window.

From your example, this would be `start /b C:\path\to\application.exe`

Comment: If I add `/b` it keeps the original window open.

Comment: If I get rid of the `start` it keeps the original window open as well.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, misunderstood the environment... a couple of things to try is to rename from `.bat` to `.cmd` and also it is worth a try to create a shortcut to your file and run the shortcut instead of the original... Please can you try these things? ... Also, try putting an exit at the end of the file!

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I tried every combination of cmd/bat; /b; shortcut I could think of and still no solution. :( Maybe you just can't do this?

Comment: @Dave - I am sure you can... If there is nothing sensitive, can you tell me a little more here or email me (details on my profile) of the program/script and I will see if I can come up with a solution... It is one of those things that just seems simple and annoying when it doesn't work - I remember trying something very similar for myself a while ago!

Comment: I edited the original question and put the actual script in there. That's the entirety of it.

Comment: I think this may be related to the program you are launching - I don't have QT and replaced it with calc, but, I just can't recreate this on Windows XP or 7, it quits the moment the file has finished. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is add `exit` to the end of your batch script and it will close the command prompt window after launching your program.

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Dave Oh, I misunderstood the original question. I didn't realize there was a second console window opening after the first one closed. I haven't been able to reproduce it (was testing with Notepad.exe). Perhaps it's just a behavior of the application you're running?